# adjust the image automatically for different resolutions

Tags: jquery, css

my web application with play framework and java allows the user to upload the image themselves. However, the image sometimes is tortured on some resolutions like mobile or tablet. Is there a way to automatically adjust(resize/crop etc) the image so it look nice on different resolutions?

Comment: Add a `css` and `html` tags to the question, you'll get correct answer faster. In general at this moment there's nothing to do for the Play framework - first you need to find accurate frontend technique which you would like to use, yet later you can write a question how to perform this technique within Play. in general there several approches, from CSS manipulation - to server side image resizing for each device (ImageMagick/GraphicsMagick + JS) and choosing final solution depends on target browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I got your question right:

You can use css to set the sizes of your images:

```
img {
   display: block;
   max-width: 100%;
   max-height: 100%;
   width: auto;
   height: auto;
}
```

This will set the image size to the defined max-size (in %, refering to the outer container) without changing the aspect ratio. Be aware that you should not set the `width` or `height` of your `img` to a fixed size so that it won't scale up to a larger size than the original image.